# Python 2 cascaded/nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to parse cassandra cfstats with Python. I have some success so far but I can't get my dictionary in format I want. I am close but not there yet.

JSON  structure I want:

```
{
"data": [{
    "{#KP}": "system_traces",
    "{#TABLE}": "events"
}, {
    "{#KP}": "system_traces",
    "{#TABLE}": "sessions"
}, {
    "{#KP}": "system",
    "{#TABLE}": "IndexInfo"
}]
}
```

JSON I am getting:

```
{
"data": [{
    "{#KP}": "system_traces"
}, {
    "{#TABLE}": "events"
}, {
    "{#TABLE}": "sessions"
}, {
    "{#KP}": "system"
}, {
    "{#TABLE}": "IndexInfo"
}, {
    "{#TABLE}": "available_ranges"
}, {
    "{#TABLE}": "batches"
}, {
    "{#TABLE}": "batchlog"
}, {
    "{#TABLE}": "built_views"
}]
}
```

Code I have so far:

```
    def parse_values(self, text):
    text = text.strip().split('\n')
    values = []

    for line in text:
        cfstats = {}
        line = line.strip()
        if not line or line.startswith('-'):
            continue

        name, value = line.strip().split(': ', 1)

        # append keyspaces and tables to list
        if name == "Keyspace":
            cfstats['{#KP}'] = value
            values.append(cfstats)
        elif name == "Table":
            cfstats['{#TABLE}'] = value
            values.append(cfstats)

    return json.dumps({'data': values})
```

Is there a way join/cascade dictionaries in Python 2?

Comment: The output you're getting suggests you have a lot more `Table` entries than you show in the desired output. What do you expect to happen with those? Do you want to repeat the same `#KP` value for each one?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code so that you only create dictionaries for the `"Table"` line, while the `"Keyspace"` lines just update a `keyspace` variable (which is used in the dictionaries for later `"Table"` lines):

```
def parse_values(self, text):
    text = text.strip().split('\n')
    values = []
    keyspace = None

    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line or line.startswith('-'):
            continue

        name, value = line.strip().split(': ', 1)

        if name == "Keyspace":
            keyspace = value
        elif name == "Table":
            values.append({'{#KP}': keyspace, '{#TABLE}': value})

    return json.dumps({'data': values})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to do this sort of manipulation.

```
import pandas as pd

dd = pd.read_json(json_data)['data'].apply(pd.Series)
dd['{#KP}'] = dd['{#KP}'].fillna(method='ffill')
dd[pd.notnull(dd['{#TABLE}'])].to_dict('records')
```

Where the last line evaluates to:

```
[{'{#KP}': 'system_traces', '{#TABLE}': 'events'},
 {'{#KP}': 'system_traces', '{#TABLE}': 'sessions'},
 {'{#KP}': 'system', '{#TABLE}': 'sessions'},
 {'{#KP}': 'system', '{#TABLE}': 'IndexInfo'},
 {'{#KP}': 'system', '{#TABLE}': 'available_ranges'},
 {'{#KP}': 'system', '{#TABLE}': 'batches'},
 {'{#KP}': 'system', '{#TABLE}': 'batchlog'},
 {'{#KP}': 'system', '{#TABLE}': 'built_views'}]
```

What this does:

1. Read json into a dataframe.
2. Fill null KP values with the value from the previous row
3. Emit all values where TABLE is not null as dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent tip. This could've work as well for me.